# how to write a streaming mapreduce job for json files in python?

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop-streaming

How to write a Mapper using python code to process a Json file in Hadoop.
I tried below code:

```
import json
import sys
data = json.loads(sys.stdin)
```

On running the above code using shell command `cat user_info.json | python mapper.py`, it is showing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapper.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = json.loads(sys.stdin)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0`enter code here`).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

The **json.loads()** function expects a string representing a JSON document; however, you are passing a [File object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object).
If your file is, for instance, with one JSON document per line, you can iterate over the standard input, line by line, and then parse each line:

```
import json
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print json.loads(line.strip())
```